# Dotcover and StatLight

Tags: silverlight, continuous-integration, teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

I'm trying to ultimately run a dotcover coverage report on my silverlight app from TeamCity.

However, I'm having trouble getting this working using the Console Runner. Has anyone managed to get DotCover to get coverage via StatLight for Silverlight apps?

This is my dotCover xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AnalyseParams>
    <Executable>BuildTools\SilverlightTestRunner\StatLight.exe</Executable>
    <Arguments>-x=&quot;Project.UI.Test.xap&quot;</Arguments>
    <WorkingDir>src\Test\Project.UI.Test\Bin\Debug</WorkingDir>
    <Output>output.xml</Output>
</AnalyseParams>
```

Comment: Suggestion: Add some of the diagnostic and environment information that would allow people to identify the source of your challenge.

Comment: Are your problem in any way related to this: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/292406?tstart=60 ?

If so, please take a moment to vote for this issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-15157

Comment: Yes, in fact I posted some comments on that post also - I have voted!

Comment: Heh, saw your name there now :) Thanks for voting, and let's hope they can get this fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that statlight kills internal browser. dotCover is unable to fetch coverage information if process is killed. 
Please vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-2290